# How to replace all occurrences of ? in string with the counter in Elixir?

Tags: regex, functional-programming, elixir

Example: `"? ? ?"` -> `"1 2 3"`

Seems like it can't be done with `Regex.replace`:

```
Regex.replace ~r/\?/, "? ? ?", fn(token) -> ...some code here... end
```

because there's no way to have a mutable counter.

Comment: It can be done--you don't need a mutable counter to do this.  I don't have the time to work out the exact code right now but it'd be along the lines of an Enum.map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, you can't have mutable counter in Regex replace, so you will have to recursively change question marks one by one. @JustMichael answer looks nice. If there can be something other than spaces between question marks, I would do it this way:

```
def number_question_marks(string), do: number_question_marks("", string, 1)

#helper takes previous and current string
#if nothing changes we end recursion
def number_question_marks(string, string, _), do: string

#if something changed we call recursively
def number_question_marks(_previous, string, counter) do
  new = Regex.replace(~r/\?/, string, inspect(counter), global: false)
  number_question_marks(string, new, counter + 1)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  "? ? ?" 
  |> String.split(" ") 
  |> Enum.map_reduce(1, fn(x, acc) -> {acc, acc + 1} end)
  |> elem(0)
  |> Enum.join(" ")
```

It works but I guess there is a shorter way to do that.

Comment: this will replace everything separated by spaces, maybe that's what the OP wants?  Your way was the method that first came to my mind.